# Can I tell when and who updated my database from v11 to v12 on Azure?

Tags: upgrade, azure-sql-database, audit

Earlier today I noticed that all my Azure SQL database servers where updated from v11 to v12. I am the only one in my company that should be touching those dials, but not the only person in my company with the access. Since I did not initiate this upgrade I would like to find out who did, and when this unplanned update occurred.

---

I know I could write an email to everyone in my company with the access asking <strike>WTF</strike> for information politely, but I'd rather start the conversation with as many facts as possible. Also, I'm inclined to think this was a Microsoft/Azure SNAFU, because upgrading all servers feels too deliberate.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this question was answered in the comments:

> It is indeed MS Azure (since you did not do it). They send you an email that on this day, the Azure SQL database servers will be upgraded. - [Kin](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/8783/kin)

> v12 has been GA since when? - [Aaron Bertrand](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1186/aaron-bertrand)

> since July 2015 I think. You're probably right that we just ran out of time. I found [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuresqldbsupport/2015/06/05/stopping-or-postponing-an-upgrade-to-sql-database-v12/), which seems to confirm your suspicion: – [Erik](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/72091/erik)

The article linked in Erik's contribution is [Stopping or Postponing an upgrade to SQL Database V12](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuresqldbsupport/2015/06/05/stopping-or-postponing-an-upgrade-to-sql-database-v12/).